# Ubuntu 14.04 - No Headphone Sound on Lenovo Thinkpad W540

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I installed a vanilla version of Ubuntu 14.04 (Desktop, 64-bit) on my Lenovo Thinkpad W540.  The sound works well on the built-in speakers, but I get no sound from the headphone jack.  In the sound settings, I can see my headphones as an available option, and I know it's not muted.  When I toggle the mute box, I can hear a little "dit" coming through the headphones as the audio feed is being disabled/enabled.  But no sounds that are sent to the headphone output is actually coming out.

I will say that when I plug in the headphones, the internal speakers mute.  But I cannot figure out why I'm getting no sound.

Attached is a screen-shot of my alsa-mixer:
[alsamixer screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwUqV.png)

I do find it a bit odd that there are two entries for the headphones.  Are there any suggestions or anyone else with a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

What struck me odd was that Linux Mint (live) had the headphone jack working properly.  This led me to look into the `/proc/asound/` directory, which I discovered was not being created at start up.

After digging around for this error, I found that by running the following installation command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

I rebooted and the headphone jack worked!  I'm not sure why these were not installed by default, but the `/proc/asound/` directory is now there and I no longer have any issues.